# Добрый день, хочу чтобы видео которое в POPUP воспроизводилось автоматически при открытии POPUP.

Tags: javascript

Сейчас видео просто произгрывается сразу при заходе на сайт (звук есть, картинки не видно)

```js
window.onload = function(){document.getElementById('popup-bg').onclick = function(e) {if (e.target != this) { return true; } popup(-1);}
  }
function popup(nm) {
    popupElm = document.getElementById("popup-bg");
    if (nm == -1) {
        popupElm.classList.remove('visible');
    } else {
        elm = popupElm.getElementsByClassName('popup');
        if (typeof nm != 'undefined')
            for (var i = elm.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (elm[i].id == "popup" + nm) {
                    elm[i].classList.add('visible');
                    popupElm.classList.add('visible');
                } else elm[i].classList.remove('visible');
            }
        else popupElm.classList.add('visible');
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="popup-bg" id="popup-bg">

  <div class="popup" id="popup2">
    <div class="head">
      <div class="close" onclick="popup(-1)">&times;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="contents video" >
      <p class="mb2">Посмотрите это видео</p>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WlnexV2eAvI?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>  
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Вы `popup-bg` создайте через js и вставьте в DOM, когда он понадобится, а не в скрытом состоянии держите.

Answer (score 3):

Для запуска/остановки видео надо послать сообщение в `<iframe>`. Чтобы эта функция работала, видео должно быть загружено в параметрами `?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer`

Работающий код ниже.

```
<body>

<p id="mb2">Посмотрите это видео</p>
<div class="popup-bg" id="popup-bg">

    <div class="popup" id="popup2">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="close" onclick="popup(-1)">&times;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="contents video" >
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WlnexV2eAvI?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<style>
    #mb2 {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
    .popup {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto !important;
        width: 560px;
        height: 315px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .popup.show {
        visibility: visible;
    }
</style>

<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('mb2').onclick = function(e) {
            var popup = document.getElementById("popup2");
            popup.classList.toggle('show');
            var video = popup.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            if (popup.classList.contains('show')) {
                video[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
                console.log(video[0]);
            }
            else {
                video[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
            }
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```

Посмотреть, как это работает, можно [на моем тестовом сайте](http://test.kagg.eu/so/623413.html). Видео показывается/скрывается по клику на текст "Посмотрите это видео".

Comment: Интересный способ, не знал, что с iframe можно так взаимодействовать. Я бы просто бы полез в api youtube и через него бы работал.

Comment: @DimenSi  С `iframe` невозможно работать по-другому. Элементы внутри `iframe` недоступны для манипуляций в js из соображений безопасности. Приведенный способ взаимодействия через сообщения является рекомендованным в документации YouTube.  И, кстати, да - это и есть использование api youtube.

Comment: Я находил только такую [документацию](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) и в ней не используется передача post сообщений в iframe.

Comment: Не надо собирать JSON конкатенацией! `JSON.stringify({event: 'command', func: 'playVideo', args: '' })`

Comment: @DimenSi косвенно в документации намекают: "Конечные пользователи должны использовать браузер с поддержкой функции HTML5 postMessage". Не помню сейчас, где и как я докопался до этого способа - через `postMessage`. Но он очень удобен - не надо создавать объект player, просто `iframe` в `html` и все.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо, поправил ответ.