# Автоматический запуск видео Youtube на сайте

Tags: html5, slider, youtube

Хочу реализовать следующее: 
в слайдере первым слайдом идёт видео из Youtube, дальше слайды с картинками и текстами.
при загрузке сайта загружается видео из Youtube и автоматически проигруется, после слайды, потом когда подходит к первому слайду - автоматический запуск видео...
пробовал вставлять так:

```html
<iframe width="520" height="293" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AH0rqwc4fgY?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

и так:

```html
<iframe width="520" height="293" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AH0rqwc4fgY?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

но в результате только картинка-заставка.  При нажатии видео запускается. Пробовал сделать как реализовано [здесь](https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/dyLAC) но снова картинка-заставка.

Пробовал как реализовано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623413/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2-popup-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8/623603#623603). JS отрабатывает без ошибок, но видео не запускается...

Comment: Здесь есть ответ, как запускать видео кодом: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623413/Добрый-день-хочу-чтобы-видео-которое-в-popup-воспроизводилось-автоматически-при/623603#623603

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Добрый день, хочу чтобы видео которое в POPUP воспроизводилось автоматически при открытии POPUP.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623413/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2-popup-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8)

Comment: к сожалению, это решение мне не подошло.... код выполняется без ошибок, но видео не запускается.... осталась показано заставка

Comment: У меня на нескольких сайтах запускается, а у вас нет ). Где-то неточно следовали рекомендациям.

Comment: Скорее всего, не добавили параметры в iframe.

Comment: я думаю, скорее всего это сам слайдер что-то добавляет... превью загружается в див сразу после фрейма  с классом ls-vpcontainer (использую лаерслайдер и там все классы имеют тот же суффикс)

Comment: Давайте кусок кода со слайдером и плеером.